# Spring boot mapping exception cannot test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to test this basic controller class and can’t seem to test the exceptions being mocked in the test. It just doesn’t seem to catch the exception, just returns `200 ok`

Update:

I have the exception now being thrown, but the controller advice is not catching them.

Controller

```java
private final Service service;

@GetMapping(value = “/cars/{id}”, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Cars>> getCar(@PathVariable final String carId) {
    var car = this.service.getCar(carId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(car);
}
```

Here is my mapping class

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class Mapper {

    @ExceptionHandler({CarNotFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> notFoundError(final CarNotFoundException ex, final ServletWebRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(NOT_FOUND).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(“test”);
    }
}
```

Exception class:

```java
public class CarNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public CarNotFoundException(final String msg, final Exception ex) {
        super(msg, ex);
    }

    public CarNotFoundException(final String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

My Test:
It just keeps returning `200`

```java
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={MyApplication.class})
public class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Test
    void should_return_404_not_found() throws Exception {
    
        when(this.service.getCar(CONSTANT.CAR_ID))
                .thenThrow(new CustomNotFoundException("not Found"));
    
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/cars/98776")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }
}
```

Comment: You checked that `CONSTANT.CAR_ID` is 98776? And you still have an error between the exception handler/advice and the one you throw in the test but it should give an HTTP 500

Comment: yes i stepped through the code, it hits the endpoint and i have a happy case working where the mock returns a response... that works fine.

Comment: @grekier I just cant seem to catch the exception, or the mock isnt throwing it. I even wrapped the controller call witha try and catch to see... but i get no exception..

Comment: Shouldn't you inject the mock service into the controller under test?

Comment: @pzelenovic As long as the bean is autowired, it will be injected. I'm starting to think that the extra `@ContextConfiguration` on the test class might override it. When debugging, is the service instance in the controller a MockBean class?

Comment: Can you reproduce `@SpringBootTest@AutoconfigureWebMvc
public class ControllerTest {..`?